# Listview to Clipboard and ContextMenu 

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, contextmenu, clipboard

I have two questions regarding listview in WPF:
1: How can I copy entire items from listview to Clipboard?
This is my code which only copies one row with binding headers (each column is binded to a list)

```
ListView1.SelectAll();
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(ListView1.SelectedItems.ToString());
```

2: I have a contextmenu on my listview and I want to  get a row number of selected row.  I have no Idea how to do that. I searched google but couldn't find any solution that works :(
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1) Iterate each item, call ToString() and accumulate in a StringBuilder. Then SetText to clipboard.

2) You should be able to take advantage of [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx).

Comment: When I use stringbuilder, I get somethings like this: { Data_Summary_Name = Lease_Name, Data_Summary_Type = Text,....  where Data_Summary_Name is the parameter name for data binding. I just want the values(Lease_Name, Text,...) in a form of comma delimited so I can copy it to excel

Comment: this is my code: System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (object item in listview1.Items)
            {
                sb.Append(item.ToString());
                sb.Append(",");
            }


            sb.AppendLine();
            System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Text, sb.ToString());

Comment: That is being returned by ToString(). Check the code for that method. Another option is to cast each item to the type its of and get the property.